# using jsPDF with Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, jspdf

I'm new to Backbonejs so maybe my problem is trivial. I want to generate a pdf with jsPDF in my backbonejs app. I'm using requirejs for scriptloading.

What I did:

1. I included the jsPDF script via bower and set the path in my main.js:

   ```
   [...],
       paths: {
           [...],
           jspdf: '../bower_components/jspdf/jspdf'
       }
   });
   [...]
   ```

This worked afaik since no error was thrown.

1. I included jsPDF in my view where I want to use it:

   ```
   define([
       'jquery',
       'jqueryui',
       'underscore',
       'backbone',
       'templates',
       'base64',
       'jspdf'
   ], function ($, ui, _, Backbone, JST, Base64, jsPDF ) {
       'use strict';
   [...]
   }
   ```
2. I tried to create a new jsPDF with:

   ```
   generatePdf: function() {
           var doc = new jsPDF();
   }
   ```

And here I got the console output 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'. What did I do wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Tim

EDIT:

Ok think I solved the problem. Since jsPDF seems to be not AMD-capable, I added

```
    jspdf: {
        exports: 'jsPDF'
    }
```

to the shim config and then it worked properly.

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok think I solved the problem. Since jsPDF seems to be not AMD-capable, I added

```
jspdf: {
    exports: 'jsPDF'
}
```

to the shim config and then it worked properly.

Comment: am still looking for AMD version